# Creating class in python tkinter (object is frame with things inside)

Tags: python, image, class, tkinter, frame

I wanted to create a gui application in python consisting of multiple objects of a class i would define. Each object would be **a frame** with **image** and **a label** inside.

I tried this:

```
 `class MyClass:
        def __init__(self)
              self.frame = Frame(root)
              self.image = None (???)
              self.label = Label(self.frame, text='default')`
```

How can i define a image without a default image? These images would be added programatically when defining that object.

Comment: What's wrong with using `self.image=None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it myself:

Just add a path to the image to the **init** function:

```
def __init__(self, imagepath)
```

Rest is the same, just define the image using this path.